# How do I get passed the Painting Soldiers in front of the stairs to the fourth floor of You in Wonderland?

Tags: persona-q

There are three Painting Soldiers in front of the last staircase in a very small walking pattern. There are also three Rose bushes that need to be painted in order to get passed them. What order do I need to paint the bushes in order to get passed them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This puzzle is symmetrical so this method will work in either direction. This answer will assume you are starting with the soldier on the right.

When you first enter the room you need to get passed the soldier on the left.

1. Walk back and forth in the two open positions by the entrance of the room until you can get passed him to the open area.
2. Then you need to get next to the rose bushes in position A4 (E3 of that tile) when the soldier on the right side of the room is directly next to them. That soldier will immediately start painting those bushes.
3. Now you need to get back passed the soldier on the left to the right side of the room.
4. Paint the rose bushes on the right side of the room (B4(C4)) when the soldier in the north section is directly next to the soldier on the right (position A4(D4)). If he is not there the soldier on the left side of the room will make it to these roses first and you will need to start over. Then you just need to get out of the way and you can continue on.

Don't forget to get the shortcut to the right of the staircase. And if you ever get stuck there are shortcut tiles on the bottom right and left sides of the room.